# gstreamer does not play back all channels of surround sound within mpegts file

Tags: gstreamer

I have an mpegts video file encoded by a silicondust hdhomerun tuner. The pipeline I have currently:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=filename.mpg ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink device=front decoder. ! deinterlace ! ffmpegcolorspace ! glimagesink
```

Works well except that it does not capture all of the audio channels.  I found this out tonight when I recorded a preseason football game and the announcers were not audible while the ref and the crowd noise was.  This same file plays fine with all audio channels in xine.

Here is the output of ffmpeg, which describes the streams:

```
Stream #0:0[0x31]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14950 kb/s, 64.96 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x34](eng): Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s16, 448 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x35](spa): Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s (visual impaired)
```

How can I get all audio channels to playback from a surround sound mpeg in gstreamer?

Extra info:

- linux OS
- alsa sound system

**Update:**

This problem is actually quite strange.  Randomly, it plays back all channels required, and I'll think I have found the solution, but then the new found solution stops working and some of the audio channels are missing again.

Even playbin2 is randomly including and excluding these channels:

gst-launch-0.10 -v playbin2 uri=file:filename.mpg

I just submitted a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682169) on bugzilla.gnome.org after determining that the intermittent behavior was also present using playbin2.

Comment: you use `alsasink device=front`, shouldn't you use something like `alsasink device=surround`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to paste that device statement.  It was just something I was trying, but device=front, device=default, or no device statement all result in missing surround channels, device=surround produces error:  Could not open audio device for playback.

Comment: Does it work, if you just use playbin2 instead of a handcrafted pipeline. Besides this would probably be better discussed din a bug report. If you can make the file available for download, develoeprs can take a look.

Comment: @ensonic, you nailed it.  I just submitted a bug report on bugzilla.gnome.org after determining that the intermittent behavior was also present using playbin2.  I forgot to update this question.  Thank you.